# Red Black Tree insertion operation keeps on crashing

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, tree, red-black-tree

I was trying to implement Red Black Tree but was unable to code it myself so I was searching for it's code written in **C** and found the below code on github I analyzed it and it was pretty straight forward and simple so I did a little modifications (just renamed a couple of variables and added a menu) and when I tried to run it I faced a problem when trying to rotate the tree. Insertion works fine until the tree get's unbalanced specially when the uncle becomes ***"Black"*** my program fails to rotate the tree and it just crashes. So Let me explain you the flow of the program: whenever we insert a new node a function named `insert` gets called, after a successful insertion it calls another function named `insertfixup` which checks whether any properties of the Red Black Tree have been violated and if so then it rotates the tree on the basis of whether the uncle of the problematic node is ***RED*** or ***BLACK*** if the uncle is ***Red*** then it works fine, but soon as the uncle becomes ***Black*** then it just crashes. Can someone please examine the code I have given below and point out what exactly is causing the problem, I doubt it has something to do with the pointers but can't figure out what is actually happening,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct RB_Tree {
    struct RB_Tree *left, *right, *parent;
    int info;
    char color;
} node;
int count = 0;

void left_rotate(node **root, node *par) {  
    node *child = par->right;

    par->right = child->left;

    if (child->left!=NULL)
        child->left->parent = par;

    child->parent = par->parent;

    if (par->parent == NULL)
        (*root) = child;
    else
    if (par == par->parent->left)
        par->parent->left = child;
    else
        par->parent->right = child; 

    child->left = par;
    par->parent = child;
}

void right_rotate(node **root, node *par) {
    node *child = par->left;

    par->left = child->right;

    if (child->right!=NULL)
        child->right->parent = par;

    child->parent = par->parent;

    if (par->parent == NULL)
        (*root) = child;
    else
    if (par = par->parent->left)
        par->parent->left = child;
    else
        par->parent->right = child;

    child->right = par;

    par->parent = child;
}

void insertFixup(node **root, node *new) {
    while (new != *root && new->parent->color == 'R') {
        node *uncle;
        //Find uncle and store uncle in "uncle" variable!

        if (new->parent == new->parent->parent->left) {
            uncle = new->parent->parent->right;
        } else {
            uncle = new->parent->parent->left;
        }

        if (uncle == NULL || uncle->color == 'B') {

            if (new->parent == new->parent->parent->left && new == new->parent->left) {
                printf("Inside ll case before rot");
                char col = new->parent->color;
                new->parent->color = new->parent->parent->color;
                new->parent->parent->color = col;

                right_rotate(root, new->parent->parent);
            }

            if (new->parent == new->parent->parent->right && new == new->parent->right) {
                char col = new->parent->color;
                new->parent->color = new->parent->parent->color;
                new->parent->parent->color = col;
                left_rotate(root, new->parent->parent);
            }

            if (new->parent == new->parent->parent->left && new == new->parent->right) {
                char col = new->color;
                new->color = new->parent->parent->color;
                new->parent->parent->color = col;
                //printf("\nHere we are in the left right!");
                left_rotate(root, new->parent);

                right_rotate(root, new->parent->parent); 
            }

            if (new->parent == new->parent->parent->right && new == new->parent->left) {
                char col = new->color;
                new->color = new->parent->parent->color;
                new->parent->parent->color = col;
                right_rotate(root, new->parent);
                left_rotate(root, new->parent->parent);
            }
        }

        if (uncle) {
            if (uncle->color == 'R') {
                uncle->color = 'B';
                new->parent->color = 'B';
                new->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                new = new->parent->parent;
            }
        }
    }

    (*root)->color = 'B';
}

void insert(node **root, int data) {
    node *new = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new->info = data;
    new->parent = new->left = new->right = NULL;

    if (*root == NULL) {
        (*root) = new;
        new->color = 'B';
    } else {
        node *par;
        node *temp = (*root);

        while (temp) {
            par = temp;
            if(new->info > temp->info)
                temp = temp->right;
            else
                temp = temp->left;
        }

        new->parent = par;

        if (par->info > new->info)
            par->left = new;
        else
            par->right = new;

        new->color = 'R';

        insertFixup(root, new);
    }
}

void main() {
    int men, c, data;
    node *root = NULL;

    while (1) {
        system("cls");
        printf("1.) Insert\n");
        printf("2.) exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &men);
        switch (men) {
          case 1:
            printf("Enter data : ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            insert(&root, data);
            printf("%d successfully added!", data);
            break;

          case 2:
            exit(0);

          default:
            printf("Invalid choice!");
            while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') {}
            break;       
        }
        getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: the header file: `conio.h` is windows specific (not portable)  Suggest rewriting such that `conio.h` and related functions are replaced with c library functions

Comment: regarding: `void main() {`   Although visual studio (and some other related compilers) allow a `void` return type, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`.  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char* argv[] )`

Comment: OT: regarding the 'menu' `printf("1.) Insert\n");
        printf("2.) exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");`  The function `printf()` is very expensive in CPU cycles.  Suggest:  `printf("%s",
               "1.) Insert\n"
               "2.) exit\n"
               "Enter your choice : ");`

Comment: OT:  the parameter to `system()` `cls` is not portable  Suggest "\f"    (formfeed)  or the ANSI escape sequence:  `printf( "\1b[2J\n" );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `int count = 0;`  The global variable: `count` is not used anywhere in the posted code.  So could (and probably should) be eliminated

Comment: what do you mean by: *it just crashes*?   Do you mean a seg fault event?  Do you mean it gets into a 'forever' loop?  Or something else?

Comment: OT:  regarding: `node *new = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));`  1)  in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing the cast.  2)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "your error message" );` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks it failed to `stderr`.

Comment: @user3629249 1.) I'm not much experienced with "C" and it's other libraries I'm not familiar with other concepts except the old one's and I have a windows machine so can you please suggest a way of using other libraries to replace conio.h? 2.) I tried using system("printf("\1b[2J\n" )); but that gave me an error 3.) I used to count variable in the inorder traversal function for printing purpose and forgot to remove it while removing the inorder function. 4.)  By crashing I mean that the console turns black and it the program doesn't show anything and the only way out become ctrl + c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Main problems**

As already said line 53

> else if(par = par->parent->left)

must be

```
else if(par == par->parent->left)
```

The algorithm in *insertFixup* is not the right one, for instance to insert the data 3 then 2 then 1 produces a crash, I see an identical definition on internet, probably you got it but unfortunately your source is bugged. That definition works :

```
void insertFixup(node **root, node *new) {
  while (new != *root && new->parent->color == 'R') {
    if (new->parent == new->parent->parent->left) {
      if (new->parent->parent->right && new->parent->parent->right->color == 'R') {
        new->parent->color = 'B';
        new->parent->parent->right->color = 'B';
        new->parent->parent->color = 'R';
        new = new->parent->parent;
      }
      else {
        if (new == new->parent->right) {
          new = new->parent;
          left_rotate(root, new);
        }

        new->parent->color = 'B';
        new->parent->parent->color = 'R';
        right_rotate(root, new->parent->parent);
      }
    }
    else {
      if (new->parent->parent->left && new->parent->parent->left->color == 'R') {
        new->parent->color = 'B';
        new->parent->parent->left->color = 'B';
        new->parent->parent->color = 'R';
        new = new->parent->parent;
      }
      else {
        if (new == new->parent->left) {
          new = new->parent;
          right_rotate(root, new);
        }

        new->parent->color = 'B';
        new->parent->parent->color = 'R';
        left_rotate(root, new->parent->parent);
      }
    }
  }

  (*root)->color = 'B';
}
```

**Additional problems**

The signature of *main * is wrong, *main* returns an *int*

If the user does not input an *int* your *scanf* line 160 does not set *men* and you can test a never initialized value. *Always* check the return value of *scanf*, for instance to be compatible with the code after :

```
if (scanf("%d", &men) != 1)
  men = -1;
```

In

> ```
> while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') {}
> ```

*c* is set but never used, and worst if you reach *EOF* for instance because the input was redirected on a file you will loop without ending. For instance do

```
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n')
  if (c == EOF)
    exit(0);
```

Line 10 :

> ```
> int count = 0;
> ```

define a global variable never used, you can remove that line

---

To check my proposal I added that function to show the tree :

```
void display(node * x){
  if (x) {
    display(x->left);
    printf("%d ", x->info);
    display(x->right);
  }
}
```

and I modified your *main* to be able to show the tree :

```
int main()
{
  int men, c, data;
  node *root = NULL;

  while (1) {
    fputs("\n"
          "1.) Insert\n"
          "2.) exit\n"
          "3.) Display tree\n"
          "Enter your choice : ",
          stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &men) != 1)
      men = -1;

    switch (men) {
    case 1:
      printf("Enter data : ");
      scanf("%d", &data);
      insert(&root, data);
      printf("%d successfully added!", data);
      break;

    case 2:
      exit(0);

    case 3:
      display(root);
      putchar('\n');
      break;

    default:
      puts("Invalid choice!");
      while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n')
        if (c == EOF)
          exit(0);
      break;       
    }
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp/t$ gcc -Wall -Wextra t.c
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp/t$ ./a.out

1.) Insert
2.) exit
3.) Display tree
Enter your choice : 1
Enter data : 3
3 successfully added!
1.) Insert
2.) exit
3.) Display tree
Enter your choice : 1
Enter data : 2
2 successfully added!
1.) Insert
2.) exit
3.) Display tree
Enter your choice : 1
Enter data : 1
1 successfully added!
1.) Insert
2.) exit
3.) Display tree
Enter your choice : 3
1 2 3 

1.) Insert
2.) exit
3.) Display tree
Enter your choice : 1
Enter data : 5
5 successfully added!
1.) Insert
2.) exit
3.) Display tree
Enter your choice : 1
Enter data : 4
4 successfully added!
1.) Insert
2.) exit
3.) Display tree
Enter your choice : 3
1 2 3 4 5 

1.) Insert
2.) exit
3.) Display tree
Enter your choice : 2
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp/t$
```

Comment: yes it works perfectly! but can you please explain a little more about checking what scanf returns? I didn't get the part where you compared it with **1** and then you put men = -1?

Comment: @ansme  *scanf* returns the number of elements it was able to read, with *scanf("%d", &men)* we want to read 1 element so if *scanf* does not return 1 that means *men* was not read. The goal is to detect the user does not enter a number but something else, like 'aze', and because in that case I set *men* to -1 that value is not 1 2 or 3 so the *default* case of the *switch* is executed and signals the bad value. I use -1 rather than 4 for instance in case a new valid case will be added for the value 4, with a negative value I take no risk to use a future valid value by error.

Comment: Understood! thank you so much for giving a brief explanation and fixing my code.

Answer (score 2):

Compile with warnings, on line 53:

```
else if(par = par->parent->left)
    par->parent->left = child;
```

you are assigning, you want to compare:

```
else if(par == par->parent->left)
    par->parent->left = child;
```

Comment: I was compiling on command prompt so that's why didn't get the warning but even after fixing line no. 53 I'm still getting the same results

Comment: @ansme yes the definition of *insertFixup* is not correct, more some other things, see my answer